# SQL query with SUBSTRING and CONTAINS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have following table

```
ID | Name | Url
```

Each `Url` contains address to file fe: "http://blah.blah.com/abcde.bin". Address is always same but file name. In need SQL query to update all cells in this column, where `Url` contains *http* and store only file name.

Example:

```
SELECT URL FROM TABLE

1 | "http://blah.blah.com/abcde.bin"

UPDATE ...

SELECT URL FROM TABLE

1 | "abcde.bin"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET URL = REPLACE(URL ,'http://blah.blah.com/','')
```

it doesn't use `contain` or `substring`, but does the same, with less code.  If it finds the `'http://blah.blah.com/'` string, it will be replaced with an empty string, so you will have just your name.

I didn't try it but I think it's correct.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If your adress is same except file name then you can do like :

```
UPDATE TABLE SET URL = REPLACE(URL ,'http://blah.blah.com/','')
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is working, but I will accept Marco Leo, because he answered before you and he need points more than you.